# Contain method in a Stack Implementation in swift

Tags: swift, data-structures, stack

Here is a stack implementation I found on the web

```
public struct Stack<T> {
  fileprivate var array = [T]()

  public var isEmpty: Bool {
    return array.isEmpty
  }

  public var count: Int {
    return array.count
  }

  public mutating func push(_ element: T) {
    array.append(element)
  }

  public mutating func pop() -> T? {
    return array.popLast()
  }

  public var top: T? {
    return array.last
  }
}
```

I wanted a simple contains method to see if an element is in the stack

Comment: What about in a collection?

Comment: You need to make a generic method and constrain it to Equatable

Comment: You must have tried *something* – don't hesitate to show your attempt!

Comment: Yeah I figured it out, before hand I was trying to use the contains(where: ) function which did not help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to mark your element as `Equatable` to check whether element available in array or not. Here `Stack<T : Equatable>` mark `T` generic element should be of type `Equatable`.

Check this code :

```
public struct Stack<T : Equatable>
{
    fileprivate var array : [T] = [T]()

    public var count : Int { return array.count }
    public var isEmpty : Bool {return array.isEmpty }

    public mutating func push(_ element : T) {
        array.append(element)
    }

    public mutating func pop() -> T? {
        return array.popLast()
    }

    public func peek() -> T? {
        return array.last
    }

    public func contains(_ element : T) -> Bool {
        return self.array.contains { (arrayElement) -> Bool in
            return element == arrayElement
        }
    }
}
```

Use of code :

```
// Create a stack and put some elements on it already.
var stackOfNames = Stack(array: ["Carl", "Lisa", "Stephanie", "Jeff", "Wade"])

// Add an element to the top of the stack.
stackOfNames.push("Mike")

print("Is contains : \(stackOfNames.contains("Carl"))") //true
```

Here my element is type of `String`, and `String` already confirming to type `Equatable`. So it will work.

```
extension String : Equatable {

    /// Returns a Boolean value indicating whether two values are equal.
    ///
    /// Equality is the inverse of inequality. For any values `a` and `b`,
    /// `a == b` implies that `a != b` is `false`.
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - lhs: A value to compare.
    ///   - rhs: Another value to compare.
    public static func ==(lhs: String, rhs: String) -> Bool
}
```

If you using your custom type and want to make use of Stack then you have to implement `Equatable` protocol for that class.

Answer (score 0):

Open up a playground to begin implementing your Swift stack!

To start off, write the following into your playground:

```
  struct Stack {
      fileprivate var array: [String] = []
    }
```

Pushing an object onto the stack is relatively straightforward. Add the following method inside the stack:

```
// 1
mutating func push(_ element: String) {
  // 2
  array.append(element)
}
```

Popping the stack is also straightforward. Add the following method inside the stack, just under the push method:

```
// 1
mutating func pop() -> String? {
  // 2
  return array.popLast()
}
```

Peeking into the stack is to check the top element of the stack. This should be relatively simple. Swift arrays have a last property that returns it’s last element without mutating itself. Try to do this yourself!

Add the following inside the stack:

```
func peek() -> String? {
  return array.last
}
```